# Can Updating symfony2 with composer break my website?

Tags: symfony

I recently downloaded a new symfony2 package for websockets and included it into my composer file, 
when I called

> php composer.phar update

It automatically updated my Symfony version and I was wondering if updating Symfony2 will break the website in the long run, since part of my source code could become obsolete (deprecated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if composer downloads a version of a dependency that's not backward compatible with the version that you used to develop your website, things might/will break.

However, you can limit the possibility by defining good rules in your `composer.json`.

First of all, it might be good to learn about [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) if you haven't heard of it already. Many projects are following the rules of semantic versioning, which basically state that if a project/library has changed in a way that is not compatible with earlier versions, it's main version number should be incremented. For instance, if 1.5.x had a certain feature, and an update is made where that feature is changed or no longer available, the new version number should be 2.0.x instead of 1.6.x.

Knowing this, you can use [Composer's tilde operator](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#next-significant-release-tilde-operator-) (`~`) to define useful version constraints. For instance, to add the dependency to symfony's files, you can add the following requirement to your composer.json:

```
"symfony/symfony": "~2.3"
```

which is equivalent to:

```
"symfony/symfony": ">=2.3,<3.0"
```

or, in plain English: 'give me a version of `symfony/symfony`, at least version 2.3 or higher, but lower than 3.0'. If Symfony follows semantic versioning correctly, no backward incompatible changes should be made in any 2.x versions (and, if any backward incompatible changes are made, they should come with version 3.0), so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This actually depends on how your `composer.json` is configured. If your dependencies use [SemVer](http://semver.org/), and you are referencing them in your `composer.json` only allowing patch version changes (like `"package-name": "1.1.x"`), then everything should usually be fine.

Also, note that you can pass a package name as a parameter to the `composer update` command, e.g. `php composer.phar update <vendor/dependency-name>`. This will tell Composer to only check if there are updates available to `<dependency-name>` package, given your current `composer.json` version constraints.

If you want to check that nothing is broken after an update and you're not keeping the update scope as narrow as I specified, then something *could* break. The best way to detect and avoid this is by testing.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [`composer.lock` file](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file). This will make sure that Composer will not update any version of the repository and only what you specify in the lock file

Comment: `composer.lock` is used to lock the current versions of your dependencies, but when you add a new dependency, you will have to run `composer update` to download it. This will also update your other dependencies, even if they're in the lock file.